# Postgres JSON, aggregating over values (regardless of keys)

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate

I have a data set like this:

```
{
"a1": {"score": "20"}, 
"a2": {"score": "30"}
}
```

And I want to get the average of the scores, but the a*N* length can vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT avg((value->>'score')::int) FROM json_each('{"a1": {"score": "20"},"a2": {"score": "30"}}'::json);
```

Comment: Yep, that makes sense to me!